# How does the for/do/done loop work in this script?

Tags: shell, unix

```
oracle@hostname:/home/oracle# cat /home/oracle/scripts/nc_profile.sh
for DB in `cat /home/oracle/SCRIPTS/lib/db_prod.lst`
do
echo "=========================================" > /home/oracle/notcomlog
echo "===============" >> /home/oracle/ncomply.log
echo $DB >> /home/oracle/ncomply.log
echo "===============" >> /home/oracle/ncomply.log
echo $DB >> /home/oracle/notcomlog
/home/oracle/scripts/nc_profile.sql $DB >> /home/oracle/ncomply.log
cat /home/oracle/ncomply.log | awk '{ print $1 "," $2}' >> /home/oracle/notcomlog
echo "=========================================" >> /home/oracle/notcomlog
mail -s  "Non compliant profile as per WG policy $DB"myemail@emailhost.com < home/oracle/ncomply.log
rm /home/oracle/notcomlog
rm /home/oracle/ncomply.log
done
```

Answer (score 0):

A bash `for` loop, iterates on each `$IFS`. By default, that's white space.

So for every line in `/home/oracle/SCRIPTS/lib/db_prod.lst` - `$DB` is set to the contents of the line. And then the loop is run as far as the `done`.

Comment: No. IFS is inter field separator. That's the dividing lines in the input